# Adding a mapping to Hosts file and cannot save

Tags: dns, host

I am trying to add a mapping to the Hosts file for my SharePoint site. Every time I hit save, it opens the Save As... dialog box and then says I need to save in My Documents, as I do not have permission to alter the Hosts file in its original location. I tried this on two accounts with Admin rights and the results were the same. Where can I enable this right?

Note: If it helps, this is for a SharePoint 2010 project. I am remotely connected to a server via RDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's anything involving permissions, odds are you need to open programs as administrator. A wise rule to abide by.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can just open your fresh notepad as administrator... and then from File menu select your host file location and open file. After that edit the host file and save.....   It will save without asking anything... :)